# Encrypting SOAP envelope using AES

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I am working on a project that requires the AES encryption of a soap envelope using the requirements below.

- Encryption key: `myKey-1234567abcdef`
- AES-256 encryption
- 128 block size
- PKCS7 padding
- 16 bit vector (vector is attached before encrypted message)
- Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)

This is what I tried:

```
$key = 'myKey-1234567abcdef';
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = substr(mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND), 0, 16);
$xml = openssl_encrypt($xml,$encryptionMethod, $key, 0, $iv);
```

I am currently getting a 400 bad request error and there seems to be lots of options for argument constants `mcrypt` functions, was wondering if my implementation satisfies the needs for padding, block size and vector?

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: AES is MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, not 256 confusingly...  This may help  https://gist.github.com/lkorth/4061732   It's kind of a messy thing, that's why I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First: Your key isn't an appropriate length for AES-256. I realize the key you're using here is an example, but make sure that the one you've been provided is 32 characters (256 bits) long. If it isn't, ask the recipient for clarification.

Second: You're mixing the mcrypt and openssl extensions inappropriately here. You shouldn't be using mcrypt anyway, as it's unmaintained, sometimes broken, and will be removed entirely in PHP 7.2. Instead, hard-code the IV size as 16 and use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` to generate it:

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$xml = openssl_encrypt($xml, $encryptionMethod, $key, 0, $iv);
```

Third: By default, `openssl_encrypt()` encodes its output as Base64. The recipient may not be expecting this. Pass `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` as the fourth argument to `openssl_encrypt()` (replacing `0`) to get unencoded output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And, sorry, yes they did ask for AES-256 encryption (see edited).

Comment: It's worth explicitly stating that you shouldn't use mcrypt because it's deprecated and hasn't been actively maintained in years.

Comment: What about decryption? would I need to provide the same vector for that?